# jquery click script not active after changes in the page

Tags: jquery, html, django

I have two jquery scripts on a list page. The first one makes list rows clickable. It works fine.

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    jQuery(document).ready(function($) {
        $(".clickableRow").click(function(e) {
            console.log('clickable row clicked');
            window.document.location = $(this).attr("href");
        });
    });
</script>
```

The second one is a search function that filter the rows and it works fine too.

```
<script type="text/javascript">

    jQuery(document).ready(function() {
        $("#search-filter").click(function (evt) {
            evt.preventDefault();
            console.log('evt triggered');
            q=$('#q').val();
            q_fields=$('#q-fields').attr('value');
            $.ajax({
                type: 'GET',
                url: $(this).attr("href"),
                datatype: 'html',
                data: {'q': q,
                    'q_fields': q_fields,
                    'title': $('#title').text()},
                success: function(code_html, status) {
                    $('#object-list').children().remove();
                    $(code_html).appendTo('#object-list');
                },
                error: function(result, status, error) {
                    alert(result);
                }
            });
        });
    });
</script>
```

It is activated by this form:

```
<form method="get" action="">
    <input id="q" type="text" name="q">
    <input id="q-fields" type="hidden" value="name, prenom" name="q_fields">
    <button id="search-filter" class="btn" type="submit" href="/contacts/ajax_update_contact_list">search</button>
</form>
```

This lattest script is a search function that filter the rows and it works fine. The problem is that when my rows are filtered, the first script doesn't work anymore.

```
<tr class="clickableRow" href="/contacts/532/">
    <td></td>
    ...
</tr>
<tr class="clickableRow" href="/contacts/533/">
    <td></td>
    ...
</tr>
```

I don't even receive the console signal "clickableRow clicked". I must have something wrong but I can't see what.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

try to make click into a function and re-call after done load ajax

```html
<script type="text/javascript">
    jQuery(document).ready(function($) {
        clickController();
    });
    function clickController()
    {
        $(".clickableRow").click(function(e) {
            console.log('clickable row clicked');
            window.document.location = $(this).attr("href");
        });

        $("#search-filter").click(function (evt) {
            evt.preventDefault();
            console.log('evt triggered');
            q=$('#q').val();
            q_fields=$('#q-fields').attr('value');
            $.ajax({
                type: 'GET',
                url: $(this).attr("href"),
                datatype: 'html',
                data: {'q': q,
                    'q_fields': q_fields,
                    'title': $('#title').text()},
                success: function(code_html, status) {
                    $('#object-list').children().remove();
                    $(code_html).appendTo('#object-list');
                    clickController(); // re-call function in here
                },
                error: function(result, status, error) {
                    alert(result);
                }
            });
        });

    }
</script>
```